# Wi-Fi Direct Discovery Not working on Android Marshmallow 6.0

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, wifip2p

```
public void discoverpeers(View v) {
    wifiP2pManager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Peer Discovery Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            Toast.makeText(WiDiActivity.this, reason + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Peer Discovery Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

The peer discovery is failing with reason=0.The Android version I'm using is 6.0. The code runs perfectly on other devices with versions lower than 6.0
I have turned on my location settings as well.
I used the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing if you can run Android's [Wi-Fi Direct demo](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo)